# Q26 from AMC 2012

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Slim took a long road trip across Australia over a number of days($x>1$).She travelled a total of 2012 km.On the first day,she travelled a whole number of kilometers and each subsequent day she travelled 1 more kilometer than the day before.What is the largest number of distance could she have travelled on the first day?

Here's what I tried:

Let the number of days be $x$ and the distance she travelled on the first day be   $y-\frac{x}{2}$

So,

$2012= y-\frac{x}{2} +y-\frac{x}{2}+1+...y...+y+\frac{x}{2}-1$

$2012=xy -\frac{x}{2} $

$4024=2xy-x $

Okay,so that's where i got stuck at already.
Is my method and concept correct?

Comment: AMC 2012 Intermediate division for Secondary 3 and 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that on the first day, Slim traveled $k$ kilometers. Then on the next day, Slim would travel $k+1$ kilometers. And then $k + 2$ on the next.

After $d$ days, Slim travels a total of $k + (k+1) + \cdots + (k+d-1)$ kilometers. So you are trying to find solutions to
$$ \begin{align}
2012 &= k + (k+1) + \cdots + (k+d-1)\\
&= kd + 1 + 2 + \cdots + d-1 \\
&= kd + \frac{d(d-1)}{2}.
\end{align}$$
This can be rewritten as
$$ 4024 = 2kd + d(d-1) =d(2k + d - 1).$$
We want to find the largest integer $k$ so that there is some integer $d$ such that the above equality holds. This is now a factoring question: what is the largest $k$ so that $4024$ splits into two factors that are $2k - 1$ apart?

Note that $4024 = 1 \cdot 4024 = 2 \cdot 2012 = 4 \cdot 1006 = 8 \cdot 503$, and these are all the factorizations we have. The only pair of factors that works are $503$ and $8$ (as this is the only pair in which one is even and the other is odd).

The difference is $503 - 8 = 495$, so that $2k-1 = 495 \implies 2k =  496 \implies k = 248$.

So Slim travelled $248$ kilometers on the first day, and took $8$ days in total to complete the journey.

Comment: Why do you need the pair to be even and odd numbers?

Comment: Because their difference is $2k - 1$, which is an odd number.

Comment: Wow,thanks for the help!

Comment: @ArcNeoepi good luck with your studies and competitions, and welcome to Math.SE! [As an aside, I notice that you've asked some nice questions and you've gotten a lot of good answers. You should show your appreciation to those who have given you good answers by upvoting them. If you consider your question completely answered, you can "accept" an answer by clicking on the checkmark. These both give some small reward to those giving you answers, and also serve as indicators of good content to other users coming across these questions and answers]

Comment: Thank you for the nice welcome and the tips. Didn't know I could do that.

Answer (score 1):

The average of $n$ consecutive integers is an integer if $n$ is odd, or an integer plus a half if $n$ is even.  So $2012/x$ must be an integer if $x$ is odd, or an integer plus a half if $x$ is even.  Considering possible values of $x$ in ascending order:

- $2012/2$ is an integer but 2 is even.
- $2012/3$ is neither an integer nor an integer plus a half.
- $2012/4$ is an integer but 4 is even.
- $2012/5$, $2012/6$ and $2012/7$ are neither an integer nor an integer plus a half.
- $2012/8 = 251.5$ is an integer plus a half and 8 is even, as required.

Hence the smallest number of days is 8, and the largest distance travelled on the first day is $251.5 - ((8-1)/2) = 248$ km.

Comment: Wow,so if I have $n$ numbers,the average of $n$ numbers(if odd) will give a integer value,but if even,will give a value which if you add half,will give an integer?Also,why must we add a half?

Comment: @ArcNeoepi  This only applies to consecutive integers.  If $n$ is odd, the average is the middle integer.  If it's even, there is no middle integer, but there is a middle pair of integers, and the average is half way between them, that is the lower integer of the pair plus a half.